# How to prevent SASS from merging files included via @import?

Tags: css, import, sass

Is it possible to prevent SASS from merging files included via `@import`?

For development, i would like to maintain the references of the original CSS (in my setup compiled from SASS already).

Comment: If this is purely for development/debugging purposes, why don't you simply enable line comments to show where each selector is coming from?  Article of interest that's likely the reasoning behind why `@import` behaves the way it does in Sass:  http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Comment: Thx for the link! What do you mean by line comments?

Comment: I've never used these config options myself, but they're documented here:  http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs for the `@import` rule says](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) that:

> All imported SCSS and Sass files will be merged together into a single CSS output file.

And explain that there is some circumstances under which it will compile to a CSS @import rule:

- If the file's extension is `.css`.
- If the filename begins with `http://`.
- If the filename is a `url()`.
- If the `@import` has any media queries.

**The following rules will tell SASS to merge *imported* files:**

```
@import "foo.scss";
@import "foo";
```

**The following rules will tell SASS to NOT merge *imported* files:**

```
@import "foo.css";
@import "foo" screen;
@import "http://foo.com/bar";
@import url(foo);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried that before, but it seems like the SASS-watcher in PhpStorm creates a real mess. Just broke everything by trying it once more. Children, don't do this at home!